# Use JMenus keystrokes in multiple windows?

Tags: java, swing, keystore

my application uses one JFrame and two child JDialogs.

The JMenubar with JMenus and Keystrokes is in one child JDialog. My Problem is that these keystrokes only work when the child JDialog is focused, not when the other JDialog or the JFrame is focused.

Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: Maybe use a different "focus situation" of the ones listed here? http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html

Comment: that must be by mistake, did you call `JMenu&JMenuItems` from 1) `JFrame`, 2) `JDialog` or from both `JFrame` and  `JDialog` too

Comment: I called `menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("meta shift S"));`. Then I added JMenuItems to JMenu, JMenu to JMenuBar, JMenuBar to JDialog.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem, KeyStrokes only go to the component (window) with focus. If does not make sense for other windows to intercept key strokes.

If you really want to do something like this then I would guess you need to look at using a [Global Event Listener](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/global-event-listeners/).